# Adding a tick and text on the x-axis of a pandas plot at a particular index in python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I want to put a text and tick at a particular index of my plot (the x axis.)

Does anyone know how I can add this?

Suppose the data I splot are

```
series.plot()
```

Comment: You'll need to interact with matplotlib directly. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14610910/1552748

Comment: Not a gridline, a tick is what I want.

Comment: Look at the answer more closely. Ticks are added and then grids are separately added afterwards.