# X-Axis Ticks labels by year with X-Axis gridlines by fiscal quarter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to set the x axis tick labels as the year but have the gridlines as the fiscal quarter.  The data is quite simple, just a groupby date.count, see below. Each date has a count and I am plotting it as a line plot.

```
rc[(rc['form']=='Bakken')&(rc['tgt']=='oil')].groupby(['date']).date.count()

date    count
2010-01-08  65
2010-01-15  68
2010-01-22  73
2010-01-29  76
2010-02-05  79
2010-02-12  76
2010-02-19  79
2010-02-26  83
2010-03-05  81
2010-03-12  83
2010-03-19  80
2010-03-26  87
2010-04-02  84
2010-04-09  87
2010-04-16  87
2010-04-23  91
2010-04-30  86
2010-05-07  92
2010-05-14  95
2010-05-21  91
2010-05-28  100
2010-06-04  96
2010-06-11  101
2010-06-18  100
2010-06-25  113
2010-07-02  112
2010-07-09  119
2010-07-16  121
2010-07-23  119
2010-07-30  115
2010-08-06  115
2010-08-13  114
2010-08-20  111
2010-08-27  114
2010-09-03  121
2010-09-10  128
2010-09-17  121
2010-09-24  118
2010-10-01  109
2010-10-08  120
2010-10-15  122
2010-10-22  120
2010-10-29  118
2010-11-05  117
2010-11-12  115
2010-11-19  113
2010-11-26  106
2010-12-03  112
2010-12-10  114
2010-12-17  122
2010-12-24  120
2010-12-31  120
2011-01-07  139
2011-01-14  141
2011-01-21  141
2011-01-28  145
2011-02-04  146
2011-02-11  145
2011-02-18  148
2011-02-25  149
2011-03-04  150
2011-03-11  149
2011-03-18  145
2011-03-25  140
2011-04-01  150
2011-04-08  153
2011-04-15  151
2011-04-22  148
2011-04-29  150
2011-05-06  148
2011-05-13  154
2011-05-20  155
2011-05-27  152
2011-06-03  158
2011-06-10  155
2011-06-17  152
2011-06-24  148
2011-07-01  160
2011-07-08  164
2011-07-15  163
2011-07-22  147
2011-07-29  158
2011-08-05  161
2011-08-12  166
2011-08-19  158
2011-08-26  154
2011-09-02  161
2011-09-09  166
2011-09-16  160
2011-09-23  169
2011-09-30  171
2011-10-07  155
2011-10-14  159
2011-10-21  156
2011-10-28  168
2011-11-04  154
2011-11-11  166
2011-11-18  168
2011-11-25  164
2011-12-02  179
2011-12-09  171
2011-12-16  172
2011-12-23  165
2011-12-30  170
2012-01-06  162
2012-01-13  172
2012-01-20  172
2012-01-27  186
2012-02-03  183
2012-02-10  175
2012-02-17  188
2012-02-24  182
2012-03-02  184
2012-03-09  189
2012-03-16  190
2012-03-23  181
2012-03-30  186
2012-04-06  180
2012-04-13  178
2012-04-20  179
2012-04-27  174
2012-05-04  201
2012-05-11  201
2012-05-18  201
2012-05-25  201
2012-06-01  206
2012-06-08  206
2012-06-15  199
2012-06-22  201
2012-06-29  186
2012-07-06  194
2012-07-13  192
2012-07-20  189
2012-07-27  189
2012-08-03  189
2012-08-10  194
2012-08-17  190
2012-08-24  192
2012-08-31  177
2012-09-07  186
2012-09-14  173
2012-09-21  178
2012-09-28  180
2012-10-05  173
2012-10-12  165
2012-10-19  167
2012-10-26  160
2012-11-02  160
2012-11-09  167
2012-11-16  159
2012-11-23  161
2012-11-30  166
2012-12-07  161
2012-12-14  150
2012-12-21  158
2012-12-28  122
2013-01-04  121
2013-01-11  115
2013-01-18  116
2013-01-25  119
2013-02-01  113
2013-02-08  112
2013-02-15  125
2013-02-22  113
2013-03-01  117
2013-03-08  113
2013-03-15  113
2013-03-22  116
2013-03-29  125
2013-04-05  113
2013-04-12  120
2013-04-19  120
2013-04-26  128
2013-05-03  131
2013-05-10  129
2013-05-17  135
2013-05-24  125
2013-05-31  140
2013-06-07  131
2013-06-14  129
2013-06-21  130
2013-06-28  139
2013-07-05  136
2013-07-12  137
2013-07-19  131
2013-07-26  132
2013-08-02  131
2013-08-09  138
2013-08-16  138
2013-08-23  140
2013-08-30  137
2013-09-06  132
2013-09-13  132
2013-09-20  129
2013-09-27  129
2013-10-04  128
2013-10-11  129
2013-10-18  130
2013-10-25  135
2013-11-01  128
2013-11-08  131
2013-11-15  130
2013-11-22  128
2013-11-29  134
2013-12-06  140
2013-12-13  131
2013-12-20  130
2013-12-27  125
2014-01-03  134
2014-01-10  138
2014-01-17  139
2014-01-24  129
2014-01-31  142
2014-02-07  145
2014-02-14  135
2014-02-21  140
2014-02-28  137
2014-03-07  148
2014-03-14  148
2014-03-21  140
2014-03-28  141
2014-04-04  148
2014-04-11  145
2014-04-18  145
2014-04-25  140
2014-05-02  157
2014-05-09  146
2014-05-16  143
2014-05-23  159
2014-05-30  152
2014-06-06  141
2014-06-13  145
2014-06-20  152
2014-06-27  145
2014-07-03  144
2014-07-11  150
2014-07-18  145
2014-07-25  146
2014-08-01  149
2014-08-08  145
2014-08-15  146
2014-08-22  151
2014-08-29  142
2014-09-05  155
2014-09-12  149
2014-09-19  158
2014-09-26  149
2014-10-03  154
2014-10-10  141
2014-10-17  150
2014-10-24  135
2014-10-31  145
2014-11-07  145
2014-11-14  155
2014-11-21  143
2014-11-26  148
2014-12-05  149
2014-12-12  151
2014-12-19  155
2014-12-26  143
2015-01-02  131
2015-01-09  132
2015-01-16  124
2015-01-23  132
2015-01-30  121
2015-02-06  116
2015-02-13  115
2015-02-20  105
2015-02-27  77
2015-03-06  73
2015-03-13  72
2015-03-20  65
2015-03-27  64
2015-04-03  65
2015-04-10  62
2015-04-17  61
2015-04-24  59
2015-05-01  56
2015-05-08  58
2015-05-15  54
2015-05-22  53
2015-05-29  50
2015-06-05  50
2015-06-12  52
2015-06-19  54
2015-06-26  52
2015-07-02  50
2015-07-10  48
2015-07-17  45
2015-07-24  44
2015-07-31  43
2015-08-07  42
2015-08-14  45
2015-08-21  45
2015-08-28  47
2015-09-04  46
2015-09-11  43
2015-09-18  43
2015-09-25  44
2015-10-02  44
2015-10-09  44
2015-10-16  40
2015-10-23  38
2015-10-30  39
2015-11-06  32
2015-11-13  30
2015-11-20  31
2015-11-27  28
2015-12-04  31
2015-12-11  26
2015-12-18  26
2015-12-25  28
2016-01-01  25
2016-01-08  26
2016-01-15  25
2016-01-22  21
2016-01-29  23
2016-02-05  20
2016-02-12  21
2016-02-19  37
2016-02-26  34
2016-03-04  32
2016-03-11  31
2016-03-18  32
2016-03-24  30
2016-04-01  27
2016-04-08  25
2016-04-15  23
2016-04-22  23
```

Comment: could you post desired DF that you want to plot?

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to do that when you responded.

Comment: it's still not quite clear what do you want to achieve? Is [that](http://s31.postimg.org/3nn8ru0zv/36801685.png) what you want?

Comment: See this post about setting custom gridlines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608483/how-to-add-a-grid-line-at-a-specific-location-in-matplotlib-plot
It shouldn't be terribly difficult to then set your minor x ticks to fiscal quarters.

Answer (score 1):

lanery pointed to right place.  you need to define you `quarters` and use in the same fashion.

#### Define `years`

```
years = ['2009-12-31', '2010-12-31', '2011-12-30', '2012-12-31',
         '2013-12-31', '2014-12-31', '2015-12-31']
```

#### Define `quarters`

```
quarters = ['2009-12-31', '2010-03-31', '2010-06-30', '2010-09-30',
            '2010-12-31', '2011-03-31', '2011-06-30', '2011-09-30',
            '2011-12-30', '2012-03-30', '2012-06-29', '2012-09-28',
            '2012-12-31', '2013-03-29', '2013-06-28', '2013-09-30',
            '2013-12-31', '2014-03-31', '2014-06-30', '2014-09-30',
            '2014-12-31', '2015-03-31', '2015-06-30', '2015-09-30',
            '2015-12-31', '2016-03-31']
```

#### Load the data you supplied

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

text = """date    count
2010-01-08  65
2010-01-15  68
2010-01-22  73
2010-01-29  76
2010-02-05  79
2010-02-12  76
2010-02-19  79
2010-02-26  83
2010-03-05  81
2010-03-12  83
2010-03-19  80
2010-03-26  87
2010-04-02  84
2010-04-09  87
2010-04-16  87
2010-04-23  91
2010-04-30  86
2010-05-07  92
2010-05-14  95
2010-05-21  91
2010-05-28  100
2010-06-04  96
2010-06-11  101
2010-06-18  100
2010-06-25  113
2010-07-02  112
2010-07-09  119
2010-07-16  121
2010-07-23  119
2010-07-30  115
2010-08-06  115
2010-08-13  114
2010-08-20  111
2010-08-27  114
2010-09-03  121
2010-09-10  128
2010-09-17  121
2010-09-24  118
2010-10-01  109
2010-10-08  120
2010-10-15  122
2010-10-22  120
2010-10-29  118
2010-11-05  117
2010-11-12  115
2010-11-19  113
2010-11-26  106
2010-12-03  112
2010-12-10  114
2010-12-17  122
2010-12-24  120
2010-12-31  120
2011-01-07  139
2011-01-14  141
2011-01-21  141
2011-01-28  145
2011-02-04  146
2011-02-11  145
2011-02-18  148
2011-02-25  149
2011-03-04  150
2011-03-11  149
2011-03-18  145
2011-03-25  140
2011-04-01  150
2011-04-08  153
2011-04-15  151
2011-04-22  148
2011-04-29  150
2011-05-06  148
2011-05-13  154
2011-05-20  155
2011-05-27  152
2011-06-03  158
2011-06-10  155
2011-06-17  152
2011-06-24  148
2011-07-01  160
2011-07-08  164
2011-07-15  163
2011-07-22  147
2011-07-29  158
2011-08-05  161
2011-08-12  166
2011-08-19  158
2011-08-26  154
2011-09-02  161
2011-09-09  166
2011-09-16  160
2011-09-23  169
2011-09-30  171
2011-10-07  155
2011-10-14  159
2011-10-21  156
2011-10-28  168
2011-11-04  154
2011-11-11  166
2011-11-18  168
2011-11-25  164
2011-12-02  179
2011-12-09  171
2011-12-16  172
2011-12-23  165
2011-12-30  170
2012-01-06  162
2012-01-13  172
2012-01-20  172
2012-01-27  186
2012-02-03  183
2012-02-10  175
2012-02-17  188
2012-02-24  182
2012-03-02  184
2012-03-09  189
2012-03-16  190
2012-03-23  181
2012-03-30  186
2012-04-06  180
2012-04-13  178
2012-04-20  179
2012-04-27  174
2012-05-04  201
2012-05-11  201
2012-05-18  201
2012-05-25  201
2012-06-01  206
2012-06-08  206
2012-06-15  199
2012-06-22  201
2012-06-29  186
2012-07-06  194
2012-07-13  192
2012-07-20  189
2012-07-27  189
2012-08-03  189
2012-08-10  194
2012-08-17  190
2012-08-24  192
2012-08-31  177
2012-09-07  186
2012-09-14  173
2012-09-21  178
2012-09-28  180
2012-10-05  173
2012-10-12  165
2012-10-19  167
2012-10-26  160
2012-11-02  160
2012-11-09  167
2012-11-16  159
2012-11-23  161
2012-11-30  166
2012-12-07  161
2012-12-14  150
2012-12-21  158
2012-12-28  122
2013-01-04  121
2013-01-11  115
2013-01-18  116
2013-01-25  119
2013-02-01  113
2013-02-08  112
2013-02-15  125
2013-02-22  113
2013-03-01  117
2013-03-08  113
2013-03-15  113
2013-03-22  116
2013-03-29  125
2013-04-05  113
2013-04-12  120
2013-04-19  120
2013-04-26  128
2013-05-03  131
2013-05-10  129
2013-05-17  135
2013-05-24  125
2013-05-31  140
2013-06-07  131
2013-06-14  129
2013-06-21  130
2013-06-28  139
2013-07-05  136
2013-07-12  137
2013-07-19  131
2013-07-26  132
2013-08-02  131
2013-08-09  138
2013-08-16  138
2013-08-23  140
2013-08-30  137
2013-09-06  132
2013-09-13  132
2013-09-20  129
2013-09-27  129
2013-10-04  128
2013-10-11  129
2013-10-18  130
2013-10-25  135
2013-11-01  128
2013-11-08  131
2013-11-15  130
2013-11-22  128
2013-11-29  134
2013-12-06  140
2013-12-13  131
2013-12-20  130
2013-12-27  125
2014-01-03  134
2014-01-10  138
2014-01-17  139
2014-01-24  129
2014-01-31  142
2014-02-07  145
2014-02-14  135
2014-02-21  140
2014-02-28  137
2014-03-07  148
2014-03-14  148
2014-03-21  140
2014-03-28  141
2014-04-04  148
2014-04-11  145
2014-04-18  145
2014-04-25  140
2014-05-02  157
2014-05-09  146
2014-05-16  143
2014-05-23  159
2014-05-30  152
2014-06-06  141
2014-06-13  145
2014-06-20  152
2014-06-27  145
2014-07-03  144
2014-07-11  150
2014-07-18  145
2014-07-25  146
2014-08-01  149
2014-08-08  145
2014-08-15  146
2014-08-22  151
2014-08-29  142
2014-09-05  155
2014-09-12  149
2014-09-19  158
2014-09-26  149
2014-10-03  154
2014-10-10  141
2014-10-17  150
2014-10-24  135
2014-10-31  145
2014-11-07  145
2014-11-14  155
2014-11-21  143
2014-11-26  148
2014-12-05  149
2014-12-12  151
2014-12-19  155
2014-12-26  143
2015-01-02  131
2015-01-09  132
2015-01-16  124
2015-01-23  132
2015-01-30  121
2015-02-06  116
2015-02-13  115
2015-02-20  105
2015-02-27  77
2015-03-06  73
2015-03-13  72
2015-03-20  65
2015-03-27  64
2015-04-03  65
2015-04-10  62
2015-04-17  61
2015-04-24  59
2015-05-01  56
2015-05-08  58
2015-05-15  54
2015-05-22  53
2015-05-29  50
2015-06-05  50
2015-06-12  52
2015-06-19  54
2015-06-26  52
2015-07-02  50
2015-07-10  48
2015-07-17  45
2015-07-24  44
2015-07-31  43
2015-08-07  42
2015-08-14  45
2015-08-21  45
2015-08-28  47
2015-09-04  46
2015-09-11  43
2015-09-18  43
2015-09-25  44
2015-10-02  44
2015-10-09  44
2015-10-16  40
2015-10-23  38
2015-10-30  39
2015-11-06  32
2015-11-13  30
2015-11-20  31
2015-11-27  28
2015-12-04  31
2015-12-11  26
2015-12-18  26
2015-12-25  28
2016-01-01  25
2016-01-08  26
2016-01-15  25
2016-01-22  21
2016-01-29  23
2016-02-05  20
2016-02-12  21
2016-02-19  37
2016-02-26  34
2016-03-04  32
2016-03-11  31
2016-03-18  32
2016-03-24  30
2016-04-01  27
2016-04-08  25
2016-04-15  23
2016-04-22  23"""
```

#### Parse your data

```
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], delim_whitespace=True)
```

## Use info from

[How to add a grid line at a specific location in matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608483/how-to-add-a-grid-line-at-a-specific-location-in-matplotlib-plot)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks(quarters, minor=True)
ax.set_xticks(years, minor=False)
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax.xaxis.grid(False, which='major')
data.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image: plot of data]