# Is there a way to specify the axis unit on the angular axis in a pyplot polar plot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Right now, my polar plots look like this:

[image]

But I need them to look like this:

[image]

Is there a way to specify a major and minor unit for both the angular and radial axes in `pyplot`? I would like to use `matplotlib` but since installing `freetype` is a huge hassle and I will have to get IT involved, I would like to see if I can do it with `pyplot`first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html) and added some lines from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608483/how-to-add-a-grid-line-at-a-specific-location-in-matplotlib-plot). Hope this fits your needs:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rmax(2)
ax.set_rticks([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2])  # less radial ticks
ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5)  # get radial labels away from plotted line
ax.grid(True)

ax.set_title("A line plot on a polar axis", va='bottom')

# angle axis
major_ticks = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 36, endpoint=False)
minor_ticks = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 360, endpoint=False)

ax.set_xticks(major_ticks, minor=False)
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)

# ls for linestyle, lw for linewidth
ax.xaxis.grid(True, ls='-', lw=2, which='major')
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')


# radial axis
# angle axis
major_ticks = np.linspace(0, 2, 4, endpoint=False)
minor_ticks = np.linspace(0, 2, 40, endpoint=False)

ax.set_yticks(major_ticks, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)

# ls for linestyle, lw for linewidth
ax.yaxis.grid(True, ls='-', lw=2, which='major')
ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='minor')

plt.show()
```

This gives the following picture [You *might* need to adjust some details ;-) ]:
[image: output]