# Is it possible to plot a map with only whole latitude or longitude?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have some code that plots a map with markers that represent a given pair of longitude and latitude (as a point).

```
df = pd.read_csv("geo.csv", delimiter=';', skiprows=0, low_memory=False)
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)   

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf.plot(ax=world.plot(figsize=(10, 6)), marker='o', color='red', markersize=15);
```

Is it possible to plot a map with only a latitude (OR longitude) "as a line"? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of way to do this! Here are a few...

#### Using matplotlib: matplotlib.pyplot.grid

One would be to add gridlines at specific lat/lons. You're just using matplotlib (i.e., not cartopy with a specific projection), so the way to do this is to set specific major and minor tick locations, then draw lines with [`matplotlib.pyplot.grid`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html). See, e.g. [How to add a grid line at a specific location in a matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608483/how-to-add-a-grid-line-at-a-specific-location-in-matplotlib-plot):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
na = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
na.plot(ax=ax)
ax.set_ylim(20, 50)
ax.set_xlim(-130, -60)
# set latitude lines as major axis ticks
ax.set_yticks([23, 30, 41], minor=False)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='major')
```

[image: map of land covering the continental United States with horizontal ticks and lines at]

#### Using cartopy: cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.gridlines

Another option is to use cartopy in your plotting ot manage projections and to add gridlines using [`cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.gridlines`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.13/matplotlib/geoaxes.html#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.gridlines). This is similar to the matplotlib option, but allows easy projection management:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import geopandas as gpd
na = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.Orthographic(-95, 35)})
na.plot(ax=ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-150, -40, 10, 60], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
# set latitude lines to be transformed into the axis's projection
ax.gridlines(ylocs=[23, 30, 41], xlocs=[]);
```

[image: similar figure, but with latitudes following a curved contour line on the Orthographic projection]

#### By manually drawing lines with matplotlib.pyplot.plot

Another option is simply to draw lines using [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). In this case, you need to decide what your [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)] points are. The simplest version of this is to use the x or y limits of the current axis:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

# set up plot
na = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
na.plot(ax=ax)
ax.set_ylim(20, 50)
ax.set_xlim(-130, -60)

# draw line using the (x1, x2) from xlim
xbounds = ax.get_xlim()
ax.plot(xbounds, [23, 23], color='grey')
ax.plot(xbounds, [30, 30], color='green')
ax.plot(xbounds, [41, 41], color='black')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is construct **LineString** for each latitude and longitude and plot them.  If you only want one then just construct the lines you want.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

# simulate a CSV to be able to use question code
p_ = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities")).sample(
    5, random_state=42
)
pd.DataFrame({"latitude": p_.geometry.y, "longitude": p_.geometry.x}).to_csv(
    "geo.csv", sep=";"
)

df = pd.read_csv("geo.csv", delimiter=";", skiprows=0, low_memory=False)
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df["longitude"], df["latitude"])]
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
ax = gdf.plot(ax=world.plot(figsize=(10, 6)), marker="o", color="red", markersize=40)

# construct linestrings for points
gdf_l = pd.concat(
    [
        gpd.GeoDataFrame(
            geometry=df["latitude"].apply(lambda l: LineString([[-180, l], [180, l]])),
            crs="epsg:4326",
        ),
        gpd.GeoDataFrame(
            geometry=df["longitude"].apply(lambda l: LineString([[l, -90], [l, 90]])),
            crs="epsg:4326",
        ),
    ]
)
gdf_l.plot(ax=ax, color="yellow")
```

[image]

Also works with interactive map:

```
m = gdf.set_crs("epsg:4326").explore(style_kwds={"radius":8}, color="red")
gdf_l.explore(m=m, color="yellow")
```